# How to fix SQL query for date function?

Tags: mysql, function

I have written the following SQL function for Monthly status report. But I am getting the reports from 30 September to 30 October. I want the results from 1 October to 31 October. What changes must be done ?

I have used following `datediff` function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.reports_to_name AS “Manager Name:Data:190”,
    d.employee_name AS “Employee Name:Data:150”,
    d.date AS “DSR Date:Date:120”,
    (CASE 
        WHEN d.holiday = 1 THEN ‘Holiday’ 
        WHEN d.dsr_pause = 1 THEN ‘On Leave’ 
        WHEN d.dsr_created_on IS NULL THEN ‘Missed DSR’ 
        WHEN d.date = d.dsr_created_on THEN ‘On Time’ 
        ELSE ‘Delayed’ 
     END) AS ‘DSR Details:Data:120’,
    DATEDIFF(d.dsr_created_on,d.date) AS “Delayed By:Data:100”,
    d.todays_tasks AS ‘Tasks List:Text:500’
FROM
    tabCalendar DSR AS d
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), d.date) BETWEEN 1 AND 31
ORDER BY 
    d.reports_to_name, d.employee_name, d.date ASC
```

I want the results to be from 1st October to 31st October or from 1st to 31st/ 30th of any month.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the where clause, this will return data from 1st date to last date of current month.

```
WHERE d.date 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))-1 DAY) 
AND LAST_DAY(NOW())
```

If you have date format like 'dd/mm/yyyy' you can use the below query

```
WHERE d.date
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))-1 DAY),"%d/%l/%Y")
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), "%d/%l/%Y")
```

Comment: @AshutoshHalape if this answer is correct mark as correct answer.

Comment: let me confirm it from my team lead.

Comment: It is not giving me the expected results.The tasks list column is empty.Even for the DSR date column as 1/11/2019 its giving me DSR details as delayed where as my previous query is showing records in DSR details as well as I am able to fetch records for tasks list column.

Comment: @AshutoshHalape I have update my answer. Please check this.

Comment: Muhammad Azim its giving me the followinf error : TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict

Comment: @AshutoshHalape Which version of sql you are using?

Comment: I am doing this in ERPNext frappe framework.ERPNext version 11

Comment: @AshutoshHalape Are you writing your sql query in python code ? and could you please share your full error ?

Comment: Muhammad Azim I am writing the query in query report in ERPNext frappe framework. Below is the only error what I am getting
Server Error: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict